# Why am i getting a error for putting a if statement in my function

Tags: python

```
    racks = "1"
racksPerSecond = 0

gameScreenChoice1 = "Traffic Drugs (1) "
gameScreenChoice2 = "Get Slaves (2) "

print("You are NBA Young Boy (Never Broke Again)")

startScreen = input("To start your journey out the trenches press 1: ")

if startScreen == "1":
    print("What do you want to do?")

    waysToGetRacks = input(gameScreenChoice1 + gameScreenChoice2)


def TrafficDrugs(slaveQuestion1):
    (

        slaveQuestion1 == input("   Push P if you want a rack")

        if TrafficDrugs(slaveQuestion1):
            racks += "1"
    )


def getSlaves():
    ()

    if waysToGetRacks == "1":
        TrafficDrugs()
    if waysToGetRacks == "2":
        getSlaves()
```

Dont ask about the varaibles, but im very confused why im getting a error

Comment: What *specific* error message are you getting? Why are there parentheses around the `TrafficDrugs` function body? Why is there a random empty set of parentheses inside `getSlaves`? Why is `TrafficDrugs` callit itself recursively without a base case?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Also, is the first line actually indented like that or is that just a function of how you copied it? Why the parens in TrafficDrugs?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need brackets inside your func:

```
def TrafficDrugs(slaveQuestion1):

        slaveQuestion1 == input("   Push P if you want a rack")

        if TrafficDrugs(slaveQuestion1):
            racks += "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't call a recursive function you have just defined you need to enter a valid parameter in order to pass the if statement.